# hamming weight of error correcting codes and BCH codes

Tags: coding-theory, span

In general the hamming weight of codewords of error correcting codes is well understood. If I were to write down the $k \times n$ generator matrix, with the span of the rows corresponding to the codewords, for many linear codes, the hamming weight is "somewhat" well understood. I was wondering if I were to look at the span of the columns of the same generator matrix, is there anything that can be said such as it is binomially distributed or etc.? In particular I am interested in BCH codes, I want to understand how the hamming weight of the span of the columns behave (hamming weight of codewords (span of rows) have been studied before by many people). Is there any literature that studies the column span?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any specific application where the span of the columns of the generator matrix is of interest? As a particular case, one form of the generator matrix is $G = [I_k \mid P]$ where $I_k$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix, and so the columns of $G$ span the $k$-dimensional space $\mathbb F_q^k$.

Comment: Well that is true. but I was wondering if there, was any bound on the number of elements in the span of the column span of the generator matrix with a particular hamming weight. I was reading a paper by Kaufman (Almost Orthogonal Linear Codes are Locally Testable) and was curious about this question.